# Forcing Linux libraries to stay resident in physical RAM?

Tags: linux, memory, shared-libraries

We have a Linux app suite that consists of about 3G of shared libraries, with many different front ends that load various portions of the shared libraries.  We run on machines with 24G, and frequently load large portions of that 3G.  We are thinking about trying to force all 3G to stay resident in RAM all the time, so that every app starts as quickly as possible.

Can this be done?  Our first thought was putting the binaries in a ramdisk like /dev/shm, but it seems like then the kernel would be free to swap the contents out, which we don't want.  We could reduce the swappiness parameter to 0, but I don't think we want that either, because file caches are a good use of memory.  We just want to dictate that this particular chunk of stuff should be kept hot all the time.

There is the mlock system call, which sounds exactly like what we want, but I'm not sure how to integrate this with a ramdisk.

Maybe we don't want a ramdisk at all, but a daemon process that simply mmaps the full extent of every binary, passing MAP_SHARED, MAP_LOCKED, and MAP_POPULATE?  Will this cause future loads by other processes to immediately access the same physical memory?  Is it correct that ld loads shared libraries using mmap with MAP_SHARED?

Any pointers appreciated!  Also any observations about why this is or isn't a good idea.

Comment: Why would you want to "integrate [mlock] with a ramdisk"? In what way would simply using `mlock()` not solve your problem? As far as I can tell, it does precisely what you want in the simplest way possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can force the linux kernel to keep the shared libraries in memory. I use for this vmtouch.

Look in this questions for more information:
https://serverfault.com/questions/43383/caching-preloading-files-on-linux-into-ram

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [prelink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prelink) in combination with swappiness tuned down to zero. If you have 24G and your box starts to swap, you are toast anyway. Prelink will force you libraries to be relocated to the same specific memory area for each library everytime it is loaded. This makes it possible for the libraries to avoid any overlapping memory ranges (on a 64 bit system at least), so every library is loaded exactly once. Additionally a small amount of memory is saved (sums up to about 100 M on my system) and of course it is faster.

In my personal opinion it is generally a good idea to tune down swappiness to 0, even on machines with less ram. It is mainly there because Andrew Morton liked it and it aims more at a low memory desktop.

> I'm gonna stick my fingers in my ears and sing "la la la" until people tell me "I set swappiness to zero and it didn't do what I wanted it to do"

Which of course never happens or only to stop the gruesome singing.

This won't disable file caches, it just avoids pages swapped out to make room for the file cache, which usually is a good idea, because swapping is much slower than reading a file from disk.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into prelink, I hadn't heard of it. I kind of doubt that I'll get clearance to alter the swappiness parameter on all our users' machines, and I hardly understand it well enough to make any sort of argument about the likely impact. But I do get the gist of your argument - no one likes waiting for long-idle processes to swap back in, even if they did get a small boost from the file cache in the interim...